# If Statement in Power Query

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, powerquery

I have a simple if Statement in Power Query I feel I need a separate set of eyes on.

I am trying to say if the current day of the week is Monday then I want the system to display whatever the date was 3 days ago, else any other day just show yesterdays date. My formula below is receiving the error "Token RightParen expected." at the "Date" after "then" on the 2nd line.

```
 if(Date.DayOfWeek(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) = 0 then
 Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-3) else
 Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few extra characters. Remove first and last parenthesis

```
let Source =  if 
Date.DayOfWeek(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) = 0 then
Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-3) else
Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-1)
in Source
```

Comment: Will accept as answer in 5 minutes. It won't let me as the question is still fresh